# error == [object Object], obtencion datos mediante php, ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

buenas espero que se encuentren bien, comento que tengo un problema el cual aun no logro solucionar.Estoy trabajando en un programa en el cual desde un modal especificamente un solo input, se deben agregar datos a una tabla y base de datos todo esto con php y ajax, cree ciertas function para poder hacer sin embargo todas me muestran en consola "error == [object Object]" la unica forma en la que me muestre lo que ingreso en consola es con este codigo "echo json_encode($data["nombre_categoria"]);", la verdad nose como solucionarlo, agradeceria cualquier aporte

```
 $('#guardar').click(function(){
       var nombre_categoria = $('#nombre_categoria').val();
      // alert(nombre_categoria);
       $.ajax({
           url: "documentos_compras.php?action=4",
           data:{nombre_categoria:nombre_categoria},
           type: "POST",
           dataType:"json",
           success: function (res) {
               //return res;
               console.log("success == "+res);
             

           },
           error: function (res) {
               //return callback();
               console.log("error == "+res);

           },
         
       });

   });
```

---

```
PHP INSERTAR DATOS
function Guardarcategoria($retval=false){

           $ret = array();

           $sql = "INSERT INTO materia_prima_categoria (nombre) values ('".$this->nombre_categoria.",'".$_COOKIE["cod_categoria"]."')";
           parent::execute($sql);
           $ret["status"] = true;
           $ret["error"] = "";
           echo json_encode($ret);
       }
```

--------Y este pedazito de codigo es el que da error-----------------------------------------

```
 function NuevoDocumentoCompras($data){
           $this->model->nombre_categoria = $data["nombre_categoria"];
           //echo $data["nombre_categoria"];
           //echo json_encode($data["nombre_categoria"]);

           $this->model->Guardarcategoria();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que en la función **Guardarcategoria**, donde creas las consulta sql y después del **.$this->nombre_categoria.** has puesto *",'"* y debería decir **"','"**, esto es, te falta una comilla simple.

Por otro lado, en la detección del error, la variable **res** es un objeto, por lo que no puedes concatenarlo a un string. Debería poner

```
console.log("error == ", res);
```

Esto es, sustituir el + por una coma

Comment: Lo hice tal cual pero ahora en consola me sale el siguiente:                               error error ==  {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

Comment: Ese es el objeto de respuesta. Con la información que te da deberías tener una idea de cuál podría ser el error, si lo hay. En especial, debería haber un campo llamado **responseText** en que que se debería devolver más información del error que se genera al *parsear* el código php.No obstante, veo que el valor de **readyState** es de 4, lo cual significa que el comando se completó con éxito, así que he de suponer que la corrección ha funcionado y que el mensaje de consola que te aparece es el de la rama **success** ¿no?.